# How do I use these commads?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I just installed Ubuntu and I used this guide: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) (the first answer).

So fast forward to number 13 it's installed and I had this problem with UEFI already that my PC automatically boots into Windows. As far as I understand that part in number 13 fixes exactly this problem.

Well, I didn't enter those commands as soon as it was installed and re-booted Ubuntu (the only option was "Restart Now" :$). Now what do I do? I tried to write those commands in terminal but this is what I got:

```
Copy:
cp: cannot stat '/target/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{efi}/ubuntu/shim*.efi': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/target/boot/efi/EFI/boot/shim.efi': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it too late now to use those commands? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I believe those commands only work if you choose to continue testing as it then is using all the default mount points the installer has for the ESP - efi system partition. What brand/model system? Some fixes work better or are different by brand/model system. Some standard work arounds: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: If you can boot you ubuntu somehow, just forget the `/target` part. During installation the newly installed system is mounted on `/target`; when you are running it, it's of course mounted on `/`. **Never** enter a command without understanding what it does.

Comment: @AlexP thanks, but it still can't access '{efi}/ubuntu/shim*.efi' and '/boot/efi/EFI/boot/shim.efi'. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Then restart the system from the installation media using Test Ubuntu, open a terminal  and recreate the installer environment -- that is, mount your root file system on `/target`, your boot partition (if any) on `/target/boot`, your EFI partition on `/target/boot/efi`, then `mount --bind` the special filesystems `/dev`, `/proc`, `/run` and `/sys` on `/target/dev`, `/target/proc`, `/targer/run` and `/target/sys`. This will make the system look like it looked just before the installation ended.